# Would this be a correct to remove Router/Handler Function in the code (Spring Boot)?

Tags: java, spring-boot

There is Spring Boot Cloud [repository](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp) on GitHub with simple route handler [example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-data-firestore-sample/src/main/java/com/example/FirestoreSampleApplication.java).

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> indexRouter(
        @Value("classpath:/static/index.html") final Resource indexHtml) {

    // Serve static index.html at root, for convenient message publishing.
    return route(
            GET("/"),
            request -> ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).bodyValue(indexHtml));
}
```

You can pay attention that index.html is in a static folder which was instantiated by Spring in default mode, so this file is loaded when index path ("/") is requested.

I understand that it is possible that some webservers will not associate main path with index.html file. However from Spring Boot and Java perspective would this be a correct not to include such Bean to the project in this case (when the main path is requested)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to test it in different contexts including Spring Boot Security and everything works well. So I close this question, however if someone has wider experience appreciate additional arguments.